# Windows monitoring issues in Zenoss

Tags: monitoring, rrdtool, zenoss

We are running Zenoss 4.2.5 and monitoring all kind of devices. We have an issue with Windows server monitoring; the rrd files are not updating on time. We have been observing the below error messages in all the collectors.

**Errors:**

> 2017-07-24 09:31:35,211 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/nsi/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:35,212 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/nsi/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:35,213 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/sppsvc/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:35,214 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/sppsvc/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:35,215 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/sppsvc/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:35,216 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/sppsvc/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:35,217 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/xagt/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:35,218 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/xagt/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:35,219 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/xagt/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:35,220 ERROR zen.RRDUtil: rrdtool reported error rrdcached: illegal attempt to update using time 1500903095.000000 when last update time is 1500903095.000000 (minimum one second step) Devices/10.64.65.78/xagt/state_state
>   2017-07-24 09:31:41,434 WARNING zen.MicrosoftWindows: receive failure on 10.75.32.13: HTTP status: 400.
>   2017-07-24 09:31:41,601 WARNING zen.MicrosoftWindows: 10.75.32.13: Windows Perfmon Error on 10.75.32.13: HTTP status: 400.

Zenpython daemon has been restarted many times but nothing is working. These errors are with Windows services, and no other errors are found. We are seeing these errors for almost all the servers.

We are seeing the broken graphs and rrd files are not updating, we are not sure the cause of these issues. But all we can see are these errors in Zenpython log file. All others data collection is running fine except for Windows.

Zenpack: ZenPacks.zenoss.Microsoft.Windows-2.7.0.egg

Regards,
Mohan

Comment: These errors look like rrdcached is seeing multiple updates for the same RRD with the same timestamp (which is not allowed).  Zenoss may be retrying multiple times?  Also, your errors are stating perfmon errors which is likely why you have no data.  Possibly you have the windows agent and/or perfmon misconfigured?

Comment: Thank you steve..

Comment: Yes zenoss is trying multiple times for same devices, and perfmon error is only for one or more devices. we not sure about the rrd errors coming in the log files.